# Wordpress plugin to edit post meta

Tags: wordpress

I need a plugin that will allow to edit post meta inside post edit page.
Can you give me link to it?I cant find plugin that fit my need.For example I tried this plugin https://surniaulula.com/extend/plugins/jsm-show-post-meta/.But it allows only show post meta, not edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post meta can be edit without any plugins, just enable the Custom Fields metabox. Click "Screen Options" on the top of the post edit page and tick the "Custom Fields" check box.

More information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields